# Why when using Powershell to specify -Xms & -Xmx do they not do anything, but work fine through Netbeans IDE?

Tags: java, memory, ram

I have a Java program which creates 4 empty byte arrays of `MAX_INTEGER - 2` length and then halts on an infinite `while` loop in the main method.

I have set my Windows Java settings to include params `-Xms12g -Xms12g` (I have 16gb RAM).
[image: Java settings]

When running the program in Netbeans IDE with the same params set for the VM, the program executes and I can see in Task Manager that ~8g RAM is being used which is about what I'd expect.
[image: Task manager Java]

I have compiled the program into a standalone .jar file so that I can run it outside from Powershell but when attempting to run the line:
`java -jar prog.jar -Xms12g -Xmx12g`
I am being told I am exceeding the heap space somehow, but I've just seen this not to be the case through an IDE:
[image: Powershell error]

`-XX:MaxPermSize=12g` seems to make no difference either, and the IDE's VM doesn't require this param.

What am I missing here?

-

*Entire sourcecode for completeness:*

```
package prog;

public class Prog
{
    public static final byte[] arr1 = new byte[Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2];
    public static final byte[] arr2 = new byte[Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2];
    public static final byte[] arr3 = new byte[Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2];
    public static final byte[] arr4 = new byte[Integer.MAX_VALUE - 2];

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        while(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it turns out, the command I needed was:

```
java -jar -Xmx12g -Xms12g prog.jar
```

not:

```
java -jar prog.jar -Xmx12g -Xms12g
```

as I'd always thought.

I had not realised the first parameters were for the JVM and the 2nd set (after the .jar) were for the .jar